# Different width of column in the HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make the width of tds different in the HTML tale but I am unable to do so.

HTML Code

```
<table class="TFtable" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th >Heading1</th>
            <th >Heading2</th>
            <th >Heading3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text jshdf hjkhsdk jhfkhds fkjhf sdjkh dsfkjh</td>
            <td >Text</td>
            <td >Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text</td>
             <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

CSS

```
.TFtable {
    width: 50%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.TFtable tr {
    padding: 7px;
    border: #4e95f4 1px solid;
}

/* provide some minimal visual accomodation for IE8 and below */
.TFtable tr {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

/*  Define the background color for all the ODD background rows  */
.TFtable tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

/*  Define the background color for all the EVEN background rows  */
.TFtable tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #BCCECE;
}

.TFtable td{
table-layout: fixed;
width: 20px;
height:auto;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Link to JSFiddle.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mayankmanu/de0cc0xx/)

Comment: what did you try so far? did you follow any tutorials about tables in html?

Comment: @hoijui Please stop this always annoying "what have you tried so far". The OP posted a link to a js fiddler!

Comment: You declare the whole table width as 50% of the view. What should the renderer do afterwards? It has to obey that and spread that width to the table cells! Don't define a fixed width for the table and you have control over the cell widths!

Comment: you should define the width in tr instead of td.

Comment: @arkascha That is a goos advice. Thanks

Comment: @hoijui I tried many things. But I guess I am too slow. :(

Comment: Remove the width: 50% from the table

Comment: you are not too slow. there are just things you don't know about this site and about html/css. you can and probably should learn both of these. people here are trying to help you to learn both. everything good! :-)

Comment: @hoijui Thank you for the kind words. I needed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this HTML Code to make different td`s width without using CSS

```
<table border="1" width="100%;"> 
          <tr>
            <th >Heading1</th>
            <th >Heading2</th>
            <th >Heading3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="20%">Text jshdf hjkhsdk jhfkhds fkjhf sdjkh dsfkjh</td>
            <td width="30%">Text</td>
            <td width="50%">Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text</td>
             <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
        </tr>

        </table>
```